# How to add string and array

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSString *butterfly = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"brush_%d.png", i]
```

I want that string in separate like this

1. brush_
2. %d.png

Because i have lot of animation function are there in my project(0 to 39).

```
if(counter == 0) {
    NSMutableArray *dashBoy = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (i = 1; i<= 13; i++) {
        butterfly = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"brush_%d.png", i];
        if ((image = [UIImage imageNamed:butterfly]))
            [dashBoy addObject:image];
    }

    [stgImageView setAnimationImages:dashBoy];
    [stgImageView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];
    [stgImageView startAnimating];
}

.
.

if(counter == 39) {
    NSMutableArray *dashBoy1 = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
        butterfly = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"catch_%d.png", i];
        if ((image = [UIImage imageNamed:butterfly]))
            [dashBoy1 addObject:image];
    }

    [stgImageView setAnimationImages:dashBoy1];
    [stgImageView setAnimationDuration:7.20f];
    [stgImageView startAnimating];
}
```

I tried this but it's not correct

```
NSArray  *c = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"brush", @"catch", @"clap",@"dog", nil];

//NSString *str = @"brush_";
NSString *str = [c componentsJoinedByString:@""];
for (int i=0; i<=3;i++)
    str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@"_%i.png ",i];
    NSLog(@"%@",str); //Output is brushcatchclapdog_0.png _1.png _2.png _3.png
```

I want

```
brush_0.png, catch_1.png, clap_2.png in array
```

Here i want to combine in one function using for loop above category.It is possible to get one function to combine the above 39 animation function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [self animateWithCategory:@"brush_" WithCount:13 duration:0.2f]

-(void)animateWithCategory:(NSString *)strCategory WithCount:(CGFloat)count duration:(NSInteger)duration{
        NSMutableArray *dashBoy = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 1; i<= count; i++) {
           NSString* butterfly = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png",strCategory ,i];
            UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:butterfly];
            [dashBoy addObject:image];
        }

        [stgImageView setAnimationImages:dashBoy];
        [stgImageView setAnimationDuration:duration];
        [stgImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
        [stgImageView startAnimating];
    }
```

Comment: animation repeat is infinite.  But i want repeat is one time

Comment: use setAnimationRepeatCount

Answer (score 0):

As per your desired output:

> I want
>
> brush_0.png, catch_1.png, clap_2.png in array

you can try like this:

```
NSArray  *c = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"brush", @"catch", @"clap",@"dog", nil];
NSMutableArray  *o =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[c count]];
//NSString *str = @"brush_";
//NSString *str = [c componentsJoinedByString:@""];
for (int i=0; i<=3;i++)
{
    NSString *str = [[c objectAtIndex:i] stringByAppendingFormat:@"_%i.png ",i];
    NSLog(@"%@",str); //Output is brushcatchclapdog_0.png _1.png _2.png _3.png

    [o addObject:str];
}//brush_0.png, catch_1.png, clap_2.png in array
NSLog(@"Output array : %@", o);
```

Logged output of the code:

```
2014-02-07 00:31:29.020 DesignMantic[807:70b] brush_0.png 
2014-02-07 00:31:29.023 DesignMantic[807:70b] catch_1.png 
2014-02-07 00:31:29.024 DesignMantic[807:70b] clap_2.png 
2014-02-07 00:31:29.025 DesignMantic[807:70b] dog_3.png 
2014-02-07 00:31:29.026 DesignMantic[807:70b] Output array : (
    "brush_0.png ",
    "catch_1.png ",
    "clap_2.png ",
    "dog_3.png "
)
```